# Passing variables in remote ssh command in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

Right now I have this file so far...

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DIRECTORY=$1

ssh root@example.com "$( cat <<'EOT'
cd /web/$DIRECTORY || exit
pwd
unset GIT_DIR
git log --oneline -n 10 --decorate
git branch
EOT
)";
```

Why does the pwd just print out "/web/"? It doesn't actually seem to be using my variable. Then all the git commands throw errors about being in the web directory.

If I have it echo $DIRECTORY out before ssh-ing, it echos out my variable, but refuses to pass it through to the ssh command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you quote the here doc delimiter. Here's [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/chap2.html#tag_001_007_004):

> If any character in *word* is quoted, the delimiter is formed by performing quote removal on word, and the here-document lines **will not be expanded**. Otherwise, the delimiter is the word itself.

And here's an example:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=42

cat << 'end'
With quotes: $var and \$var
end

cat << end
Without quotes: $var and \$var
end
```

When executed:

```
With quotes: $var and \$var
Without quotes: 42 and $var
```